# npm WARN deprecated swagger-ui@2.2.10: No longer maintained, please upgrade to swagger-ui@3

Tags: swagger

I get this message and when I uninstall Swagger with:

D:\08> npm uninstall -g swagger

and install it again:

D:\08> npm install -g swagger

I get a version that is not 3:

D:\08>swagger --version
0.7.5

What should I do to really upgrade or install swagger? Or may be i really got the upgrade I'm looking for?

Thanks